# How to cancel the day's recurring notifications in UserNotifications

Tags: swiftui, usernotifications

I am developing a Todos App based on SwiftUI. It can notify users at a fixed time every day if they don't finish today's todos, I use the UserNotifications to implement the notification function. Currently I want to cancel the notification of the day if users finished their todos. So how can I implement based on UserNotifications?

Answer (score 1):

To remove all at once:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
```

To remove some separately:

1. store ids of created notifications anywhere
2. then call

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [<ids you want to cancel>])
```

Comment: Yes, I can remove the scheduling notification when users finished their todos, and then re-schedule the notification from next day. But it seems that UserNotifications do not support scheduling the notification from a future date.